# Selenium getattribute list c#

Tags: c#, html, selenium-webdriver, lista

Estou com um problema para criar uma `list` com atributos segue código HTML:

```
 <div class="post  clearfix" data-post-id="92842173">...</div>
 <div class="post  clearfix" data-post-id="92841636">...</div>
 <div class="post  clearfix" data-post-id="92618462">...</div>
 <div class="post  clearfix" data-post-id="90658834">...</div>
```

código c# atual:

```
var valor = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'post')]")).GetAttribute("data-post-id");
```

assim só pego o primeiro `data-post-id="92842173"`.

Gostaria de criar uma lista com todos os `data-post-id`. Já tentei fazer da seguinte maneira abaixo, porém dá erro.

```
List <IWebElement> list1  = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'post')]")).GetAttribute("data-post-id");
```

Comment: o chromeDriver não tem um método FindElements?

Comment: sim, ele tem, eu utilizo pra localizar a div aonde contem o atributo que preciso extrair, mas não consigo extrair todos ou 1 por 1, so consigo extrai o 1° atributo, preciso de uma função pra extrair todos os data-post-id.

Comment: Veja se tem algo como FindAllElement ou selectElement no seu chromeDriver

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá,
existe um método no **Selenium** pra poder pegar mais de um elemento usando uma mesma referência, no caso esse caminho que você utilizou pra achar o primeiro:

```
By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'post')]");
```

Ao invés de usar

```
List <IWebElement> list1  = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'post')]"))
```

você usará

```
IList<IWebElement> list1 = chromeDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'post')]"));
```

Pronto, agora que você tem uma lista com todos esses `IWebElement`, falta agora extrair os `data-post-id` de cada um, vamos supor que você queira armazená-los em um `List`, então ficará assim:

```
List<string> dataPost = new List<string>();

for(int i = 0; i < list1.Count(); i++){
    dataPost.Add(list1[i].GetAttribute("data-post-id"));
}
```